# AJAX with Codeigniter load view automatically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am looking for help with AJAX and CodeIgniter. I am trying to load a view automatically as the page loads but it doesn't work as expected.

Here is the AJAX code in the view:

```
$(document).ready ( function(){
    var datas = "badili";
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url('wapi/featured'); ?>",
        type: 'POST',
        data: { view: datas },
        success: function(response) {
            $('#thechange').html(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Then in the controller I have created a function that loads the page and feeds it into the div of the view:

```
public function featured() {
    $dat = $this->input->post('view');
    if ($dat != "") {
        $this->load->view('featured_wapi');
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't work as expected" ? What's the ouput of your controller ?

Comment: It is not working doen't load ant thing

Comment: Try to dump the content of your $dat var in the controller

Comment: open your browsers console, check if the network tab shows anything

Comment: May be **url: "<?php echo site_url('wapi/featured'); ?>",** can help

Comment: ReferenceError: $ is not defined in the console

Comment: i used site_url an still its not working

Comment: Are you load the jquery.min.js file in your page ? check it

Comment: Yes i am but i get Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.

Comment: chk your jquery version ... test it with jQuery also

Answer (score 0):

You need to echo view data from action "featured". Use following code in action.

```
public function featured() {
$dat = $this->input->post('view');
if ($dat != "") {
    echo $this->load->view('featured_wapi', true);
}}
```